# Firefox keyboard shortcut to save current page to Pocket

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

Using the Pocket integration built into Firefox 38+, how can I make a keyboard shortcut to save the current page to Pocket?

Comment: Doing a google search of your title, it seems that this is not possible nativley. Top result being this question in mozilla support website. There was another addon, "shortcutkey2url" that looked like it could make this happen, however

Comment: As you point out, this is exactly how to do it. Thanks! https://codeyarns.com/2015/09/26/how-to-save-to-pocket-using-keyboard-shortcut-in-firefox/

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help. I'll turn my comment into an answer so you have something to complete the question with!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing a google search of your title, it seems that this is not possible nativley. Top result being this question in mozilla support website. There was another addon, "shortcutkey2url" that looked like it could make this happen, however

https://codeyarns.com/2015/09/26/how-to-save-to-pocket-using-keyboard-shortcut-in-firefox/

Answer (score 0):

I am using the addon [In My Pocket](https://inmypocketaddon.com/) which is working perfectly with hotkey for me, only disadvantage so far is the missing functionality of adding tags to saved pages.

You can fast access your list (with hotkey), great support also.